# How to get MATLAB handle object name as a string?

Tags: oop, matlab

Is there a way to get the name of a MATLAB handle object as a string?

Answer (score 3):

Overwrite [`disp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/handle.html) method of your from `handle` derived class! If you mean the type then call `class(obj)`